# Issue with jQuery ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've following `jQuery code`,

```
 $("#tabs").tabs({
  select: function(event, ui) {                   
    window.location.replace(ui.tab.hash);
},}).addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
```

Except first tab for all other `tabs` jQuery adding a `style` attribute value `display:none`,due this I'm getting error while loading `openlayers map` in second tab.Because while creating the `map` its corresponding `div` is in `hidden` state.So I added below code,

```
$("#tabs").tabs("widget").find('#tab-2').attr('style','display:block');
```

But this leads to another problem,while loading the third tab,second tab is also in `visible` state,is there any alternate solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem not using jqueryui. Because I could control the the way the tabs worked I set the width and height to 0 rather than using display: none to hide the tabs this allowed the map - gmaps in my case to render.

The other thing to look at as a callback. I.E render the map on the click of the tab rather than when the page loads. There is a method for doing this I think: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

Update: I actually ended up doing the second of these ideas but as I said I wrote my own tabs so it was bit easier.

Comment: If I keep the `map` related code in `activate callback function` then `map` is loading perfectly as expected, but when I refresh the page while in second tab then `map` is not loading.

Comment: you need to use the call back whenever you load the map

Comment: which call back I should use ?

Comment: If move `map` related code to `show callback function` then everything is working as expected,anyhow thanks for your support.